# php script works when running in browser but doesn't when running cron event

Tags: php, mysql, xml, cron

I've got a php script page which uses some Vebra API to store property information into a MySQL database. I currently have for loops as you require to firstly get the branch information in XML then use the url from this to get the property id's for each branch as an XML and then request the property information using the url of each property ID also sorted in XML.

This loops and then adds all the information into MySQL. This all works fine in browser but when running as a cron it doesn't complete.

The connect script is below. In the live version it has a username and password with datafeedid. I then run the connect function at the bottom and then forloop the results.

```
session_start();

            //Define Your Unique Variable Here:
            $username = "";
            $password = "";
            $datafeedID = "";
            $request = "http://webservices.vebra.com/export/$datafeedID/v1/branch";

            //Function to authenticate self to API and return/store the Token
            function getToken($url) {

                //Re-define username and password variable scope so they can be used within the function
                global $username, $password;

                //Overwiting the response headers from each attempt in this file (for information only)
                $file = "headers.txt";
                $fh = fopen($file, "w");

                //Start curl session
                $ch = curl_init($url);
                //Define Basic HTTP Authentication method
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
                //Provide Username and Password Details
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
                //Show headers in returned data but not body as we are only using this curl session to aquire and store the token
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); 
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1); 
                //write the output (returned headers) to file
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fh);
                //execute curl session
                curl_exec($ch);
                // close curl session
                curl_close($ch); 
                //close headers.txt file
                fclose($fh); 

                //read each line of the returned headers back into an array
                $headers = file('headers.txt', FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

                //for each line of the array explode the line by ':' (Seperating the header name from its value)
                foreach ($headers as $headerLine) {

                    $line = explode(':', $headerLine);
                    $header = $line[0];
                    $value = trim($line[1]);

                    //If the request is successful and we are returned a token
                    if($header == "Token") {
                            //save token start and expire time (roughly)
                            $tokenStart = time(); 
                            $tokenExpire = $tokenStart + 60*60; 
                            //save the token in a session variable (base 64 encoded)
                            $_SESSION['token'] = base64_encode($value); 

                            //For now write this new token, its start and expiry datetime into a .txt (appending not overwriting - this is for reference in case you loose your session data)
                            $file = "tokens.txt";
                            $fh = fopen($file, "a+");
                            //write the line in
                            $newLine = "'".$_SESSION['token']."','".date('d/m/Y H:i:s', $tokenStart)."','".date('d/m/Y H:i:s', $tokenExpire)."'"."\n";
                            fwrite($fh, $newLine);
                            //Close file
                            fclose($fh);
                        }

                }

                //If we have been given a token request XML from the API authenticating using the token
                if (!empty($_SESSION['token'])) {
                    connect($url);
                } else {
                    //If we have not been given a new token its because we already have a live token which has not expired yet (check the tokens.txt file)
                    echo '<br />There is still an active Token, you must wait for this token to expire before a new one can be requested!<br />';
                }
            }

            //Function to connect to the API authenticating ourself with the token we have been given
            function connect($url) {

                //If token is not set skip to else condition to request a new token 
                if(!empty($_SESSION['token'])) {

                    //Set a new file name and create a new file handle for our returned XML
                    $file = "test.xml";
                    $fh = fopen($file, "w");

                    //Initiate a new curl session
                    $ch = curl_init($url);
                    //Don't require header this time as curl_getinfo will tell us if we get HTTP 200 or 401
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
                    //Provide Token in header
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Basic '.$_SESSION['token']));
                    //Write returned XML to file
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fh);
                    //Execute the curl session
                    curl_exec($ch);

                    //Store the curl session info/returned headers into the $info array
                    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);

                    //Check if we have been authorised or not
                    if($info['http_code'] == '401') {
                        getToken($url);
                        echo 'Token Failed - getToken() has been run!<br />';
                    } elseif ($info['http_code'] == '200') {
                        echo 'Token Worked - Success';
                    }

                    //Close the curl session
                    curl_close($ch);
                    //Close the open file handle
                    fclose($fh);

                } else {

                    //Run the getToken function above if we are not authenticated
                    getToken($url);

                }

            }

            //Connect to the API using connect() function above
            connect($request);
```

Comment: What does _'doesn't complete'_ mean? Do you have any errors? Have you made any attempt to debug this?

Comment: Look in the error logs?

Comment: what is your cron command?

Comment: I do apologise. The fix for this was typing the full location of the xml files for when to save them and for when to run simplexml_load_file. Worked in browser fine but the cron doesn't run from the same folder.

Answer (score 0):

The fix for this was typing the full location of the xml